# gnome-shell shortcut for opening new instance

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

In gnome-shell hitting enter for a search result opens the application in the current workspace or brings up the currently open instance of the app. Is it possible to have a shortcut (like: Alt + Enter or something) that opens a new instance of the application in the current workspace or in a new workspace.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the Ctrl key?  This works me in Gnome 3.2.

Comment: Ctrl takes care of opening another instance of an application in the same workspace. The other desirable thing here is opening an application in a new workspace. This can be achieved with middle-click, but is there a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing?